# Is there such a thing as standard text for learning accents?

Tags: accent

I've been trying to learn accents and have been fortunate enough to make friends in some of the countries I want to emulate.

I was wondering if there is a standard block of text containing all the key phonemes that they might read that would help me get the basics? Honestly, I know *nothing* about linguistics, I don't even know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Study phonetics, then practice on [transcribed accent samples](http://accent.gmu.edu/). The only book you need is Catford's _A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_.

Comment: Oh my gosh this site is fantastic. That's actually exactly what I was looking for! I can just have my friends read this text.

Comment: @jlawler mind to post that as answer, perhaps with some context? :D